# Detect if sensor data is trending upwards with value overflow

Tags: python, data-science

I am reading data from sensor over time and I need to check whether it is trending upwards. I know how to do that, but sensor at some point reaches max value and starts over and I need to be able to ignore this rollover. How to correctly deal with this so that I correctly find the data trend, but also correctly deal with the overflow at the same time. Examples of data that I could receive include (overflows at 255):

```
data = [191, 198, 204, 217, 230, 241, 255, 17, 32, 67, 90, 117]
```

```
data = [113, 182, 201, 9, 74, 91, 148, 182, 231, 41, 72, 100]
```

Comment: I assume you want to calculate the trend on a moving window, let's say the last 20 values or so? And 255 should not be included in trend calculation if I understand correctly? Please provide your code for the trend calculation, as the question is I can just suggest to use an if-statement to check if the value is 255, then do or do not something.

Comment: I want to calculate the trend for entire data. It is real sensor data, the value overflows at 255, but data steps may be quite large sometimes and you may skip 255, so checking if data point is equal to 255 is pointless, that is why I provided example data

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure how would you normally check if there is a data overflow after 255 or it's a descending trend.
I think that you could put a threshold (considering your data differences, a threshold of 100 should be enough) which would verify if 2 consecutive values could be differentiated by the data overflow or by a descending trend.
Can your data values go down, or only grow (Ex: 113,182, 160, 120)?

1. If they can only grow as values, you could simply check if a value is smaller than the previous one, and if yes, increment it with 255*times_of_overflow
2. If the value can get smaller too, i think a threshold would be your best option (if a value gets from 201 to 9, the difference would be 192>threshold, so it means there had been an overflow)

Comment: unpredictable trend downwards would indicate defective sensor which I am trying to prevent, however, few times value cant get a little bit smaller, as you might expect, sensors are not perfect, e.g. data = [209, 209, 210, 211, 210, 211, 212, 212, 213, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 215, 216, 217]. The trend is upwards, however, it drops ocasionally. Your comment was helpful however, I will try second method.

Answer (score 0):

here is a code to calculate the trend coefficient:

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress

def global_trend_coef(data):
    """Calculates global trend of a time series data
    """
    t=[i+1 for i in range(len(data))]
    return float('%.2f' % linregress(t, data).slope)
```

And this display global direction taken by the data:

```py
def global_trend_direction(data):
    """Displays a global trend direction of a time series data
    """
    trend=global_trend_coef(data)
    if trend >= 0.0:
        print('upwards')
    else:
        print('downwards')
```